# PowerShell Find a string a copy subsequent lines

Tags: powershell

I am trying to find a string in a text file and when found, I want to copy the line where the string was found and also copy the following 3 lines.

Using PowerShell, I tried this command:

```
$string = "January"
$dataRead = "C:\Monthly.txt
Select-String $string $dataRead -Context 0, 3 | % {$_.Context.PostContext} | out-file "C:\Results.txt"
```

(These lines are from a larger script that does other processes such as file copies.)

When it runs, the Out-File gives me the 3 lines following where my keyword was found. If I change Context to 4, then I get the next 4 lines, not actually starting with the line I need.

How can I copy the line with the keyword plus the 3 lines that immediately follow?

Answer (score 4):

You Just needed to add in your line as you have only selected the post context.

```
$string = "January"
$dataRead = "C:\Monthly.txt"

Select-String $string $dataRead -Context 0, 3 | % { $_.line + $_.Context.PostContext } |  out-file "C:\Results.txt"
```

Should you have require a single line PreContext you would need to add in respectively

```
Select-String $string $dataRead -Context 1, 3 | % { $_.context.PreContext + $_.line + $_.Context.PostContext } |  out-file "C:\Results.txt"
```

Comment: Hi Antony.  Thankyou for your reply.  That worked perfectly. It was exactly the result I needed and I was looking for.  I used the 2nd suggestion and it was dead on.  Thankyou.